# Implementing Circular Array Queue

Tags: c++

I am to implement a Circular Array Queue But I a having logical errors and I  am not getting the correct result. I need help implementing bool dequeue() in ArrayQueueP4.h. I doubt if it is correct.

.

I have tried different solutions as well as search through previous questions on stack overflow and online yet it did not give me any ideas on what I am looking for

```
#ifndef ARRAY_QUEUE_P4_
#define ARRAY_QUEUE_P4_
#include "QueueInterface.h"
#include "PrecondViolatedExcept.h"

template<class ItemType>
class ArrayQueueP4 : public QueueInterface<ItemType>
{
private:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 50;
    ItemType items[DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1]; // Array of queue items
    int front;                   // Index to front of queue
    int back;                    // Index to back of queue

public:
    ArrayQueueP4() : front(DEFAULT_CAPACITY),
        back(DEFAULT_CAPACITY) {};
    // Copy constructor and destructor supplied by compiler
    bool isEmpty() const;
    bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry);
    bool dequeue();

    /** @throw  PrecondViolatedExcept if queue is empty. */
    ItemType peekFront() const;
};

ArrayQueueP4.h is the header file for ArrayQueueP4.cpp
#include "ArrayQueueP4.h";

#include "PrecondViolatedExcept.h";

using namespace std;

template <class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueueP4 <ItemType>::isEmpty() const {
    return (front == back);
}

template <class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueueP4 <ItemType>::enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) {

    if (!isEmpty())

    back = (back + 1) % DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
    items[back] = newEntry;
    back++;
    return true;


}

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueueP4 <ItemType> ::dequeue() {
    bool result = false;
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        front = (front + 1) % DEFAULT_CAPACITY;
        front--;
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}

template<class ItemType>
ItemType ArrayQueueP4<ItemType>::peekFront() const {

    if (isEmpty())
        throw PrecondViolatedExcept("peekFront() called with an empty queue.");
    else
        return items[front];

}

HERE is my main file main.cpp to test my code


#include <iostream>

#include "ArrayQueueP4.cpp";

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ArrayQueueP4<int> AP;
    AP.enqueue(1);
    AP.enqueue(2);
    AP.enqueue(3);

    /*LinkedQueueP1<int> LP;
    LP.enqueue(1);
    LP.enqueue(2);*/

    cout << "PEEK FRONT: " << AP.peekFront();
    //cout << "PEEK FRONT: " << LP.peekFront();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Based on my main program file, the output supposed to now 1 when I call the enqueue function. But instead of getting 2 as my answer, I am getting -858993460 as my result when I delete the first item using dequeue(). I do not know if that is how Queues behave but isn't the second number supposed to be the next first item in line when I delete the first number?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: That is what I did. My problem comes from these functions: bool isEmpty() const, bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) and bool dequeue(). I do not know how to solve it yet but I noticed that is where my problem is coming from. I edited my post to be clear not too long ago.

Comment: `enqueue()` looks suspicious. The only time you move the writing index (`back`) is when the quueue is _not_ empty. How can the reader know that you put've an element in the queue if you don't do `back = (back + 1) % DEFAULT_CAPACITY;` whenever you put something in the queue?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Thank you for reaching out to me. I have fixed bool isEmpty() const and bool enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) function. My engueue function gave me errrors because I forgot to increment back and I am supposed to set front == back in my isEmpty function to show when the QUEUE is empty. Luckily for me, I fixed that and it is working. Please can you take a look at bool dequeue() function and tell. where I went wrong?

Comment: You have to be very specific about what your `front` and `back` means, and stick to this definition through out the program! Many times those indices take the meaning of `+1/-1` offset from their real literal meaning (think of the `end()` method of many stl containers, it means `pass then end`, not the last element). And here are some extra hints that might help you: (1) How do you detect when a queue is full? (2) What should you initialize `front` and `back` with?

Comment: If you have changed your code to fix small errors, you need to update the question with those fixes too. Also, make it a [mcve] so we can compile it too.

Comment: Also, just as a personal preference, implementing circular queue using the `back` and `front` model can be tedious. I prefer using `front` and `count`.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9171697/kaenbyou-rin I know what you are saying. I have thought about trying that too. But this is an assignment given to me by my teacher. If I go out of her scope, she will penalize me. I am required to implement ArrayQueueP4.cpp without editing her code. Unless you mean that I should declare count as a local variable not a private variable in my header file.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo sure I will edit it.

Comment: @Kaenbyou Rin I am sticking to the definition of the program. Based on my code, front means the front of the queue which is the first Item to be removed, while, back means the back of the queue where the items are to be inserted. The queue is full if front equals (back + 1) % (DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1). To specify when the queue is full, I am to create a function called isFull() to make things easier. But I will not do that because my teacher  didn't say so and I do not want to edit her code. I will lose points for that.

Comment: I have edited my code

Comment: @Respawn It's still not a [mcve] even after the edit.

Comment: @Respawn -- Advice -- Use pencil and paper to diagram and to plan how you want to solve your problem before writing any further code.  You are not going to figure out what's wrong by trying pieces of code and seeing what sticks.  With no plan, you won't get too far.  When you have a plan drawn out on paper, then and only then do you write the code to fit the plan.  If after doing that things are still not working, then use a debugger to see where the program goes against the plan you have drawn on paper.  Then it's either you fix the bugs, or you discover your plan was flawed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, your `front` and `back` defines a range, such that `front` is the first element available in the queue, and `back` is the "pass-the-end" index. Then according to those definition the code should look like this:

```cpp
template <class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueueP4 <ItemType>::enqueue(const ItemType& newEntry) {
    // Check if queue is full
    if ((back + 1) % (DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1) == front) return false;
    // Append element at one-pass-end position
    items[back] = newEntry;
    // Update the one-pass-end index (back)
    // All your modulo operation should be dealing with DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1
    // because that is the size of your array
    back = (back + 1) % (DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1);
    return true;
}

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayQueueP4 <ItemType> ::dequeue() {
    // Dequeue fail if the queue is empty
    if (isEmpty()) return false;
    front = (front + 1) % (DEFAULT_CAPACITY + 1);
    return true;
}
```

---

Also, as a reminder, your code does not take resource management in to account (although it works for most types and doesn't seem to make any mistakes). When an item is dequeued, it's corresponding resources should be released. As an exercise, think about the scenario where `ItemType` is `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr`). This is probably not what your teacher wants, but it is a good practice.